# R apply on a matrix a function of columns and row index

Tags: r, matrix, apply, lapply

I would like to apply on a matrix a function of both the value, the row index and the column index for every value in the matrix and get the transformed matrix.
For example

```
mat<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)    
mat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

f<-function(x,i,j){x+i+j}
mat2 <- my.apply(f,mat)
mat2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    6
[2,]    5    8
```

The example above is for illustration purposes, `f` can be much more complex.

`apply` does not do the job, because of the way the extra arguments are handled.

```
apply(mat,1:2,f,seq_along(mat[,1]),seq_along(mat[1,]))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    5    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    6
[2,]    7    8
```

I can not find either a way with the `lapply` family. A `for` loop can do the job but it won't be efficient nor elegant.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: If your function is vectorized then `f(mat, row(mat), col(mat))` should work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `mapply`

```
mat <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2)
mat
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    3
## [2,]    2    4


matrix(mapply(function(x, i, j) x + i + j, mat, row(mat), col(mat)), nrow = nrow(mat))
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    3    6
## [2,]    5    8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly use of apply, just for some quick and dirty job. The trick is adding an additional column (or row) for row (or column) indices.

```
mat <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2)
t(apply(cbind(mat, 1:nrow(mat)), 1, function(x){x[1:ncol(mat)] + 1:ncol(mat) + x[ncol(mat)+1]}))
##     [,1] [,2]
##[1,]    3    5
##[2,]    6    8
```

If you have a function `f(x, i, j)` already, you can also try:

```
apply(cbind(mat, 1:nrow(mat)), 1, function(x){a = numeric(); for(j in 1:ncol(mat)){a[j] = f(x[j], x[ncol(mat)+1], j)}; a})
```